# How to initialise array of TCHAR?

Tags: c++, c

There are following methods to initialise null value.

```
TCHAR x[5] = {'\0'};
TCHAR x[5] = _T("\0");
```

I want to know which is the right one?

Comment: Do you understand what `_T` does though?

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different. Please tag your question with only one of them.

Comment: unless you're targeting Windows 95,  the best solution is to not use `TCHAR` at all. Select `char` or `wchar_t` depending on what you intend to store.

Comment: @M.M Quoting your comment in my answer. I hope you won't mind.

Comment: @MohitJain that's fine

Answer (score 4):

Use the former one. `_T(...)` will generate an emtpty string of `char` or `wchar` according to the project settings. Latter example (without `_T(...)` would fail compilation if multibyte character set<sup>[a]</sup> is used..

One possible definition of `_T` is:

```
#if defined(_UNICODE)
#  define _T(x) L ##x
#else
#  define _T(x) x
#endif
```

Quoting from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692396/how-to-initialise-array-of-tchar#comment59062470_35692396) to complete this answer:

> unless you're targeting Windows 95, the best solution is to **not**
>   use `TCHAR` at all. Select `char` or `wchar_t` depending on what you
>   intend to store

---

After the question is changed, following are my comments:

1. Both declarations are same if you are not targeting multi-byte char. The only difference is, first one is convenient if you don't want a null terminated array and second one (`TCHAR x[5] = _T("\0");`) is convenient to initialize from a string and provide a null termination. But in this case both are equivalent.
2. If the target is multi-byte charcter, even then both declarations are same because implicit conversion is available from `char` to `wchar_t`.

So both declarations are equivalent, choose the one that you find more readable.

---

<sup>[a] For MSVC: Project settings > Configuration Properties > Project Defaults > Character Set</sup>

Comment: Hi Mohit, there was some mistake. I modified it. pl have a look

Comment: @user966379 Updated my answer. Avoid changing the question as it can make all the available answers invalid.